# Swap first and last letter of a string in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ternary-operator

I hope I'm missing something obvious here, but I was playing around with the Python CodingBat site, and got to the problem [front_back](http://codingbat.com/prob/p153599):

> For a string passed in, return it with its first and last characters swapped, if the string length is greater than 1.

I came up with a single line solution which I thought would suffice but Coding.bat refuses to accept it, with an Index out of range error.

I've played around in IDLE (64bit windows version) and I've boiled the problem down to this:

```
len(str) < 2 and str or 'doh ' + str + ' /doh'
```

The wierd problem is that setting `str = ''` returns:

```
'doh  /doh'
```

Which it shouldn't as len('') is 0, but `str='a'` returns:

```
'a'
```

and `str='abc'` returns:

```
'doh abc /doh'
```

Which I would expect...

So my question is really; Why is checking the len of '' going to the OR condition of the ternary operator, but running `len('')` at the console return 0, which is obviously less than 2?

**Edit:**

This solution actually works, however:

```
  def front_back(str):
    if len(str)  < 2:
        return str
    else:
        return str[-1] + str[1:-1] + str[0]
```

To 'mtadd'; thanks for your answer but this isn't a logical and/or this is a pythonic ternary operator:

```
return (statement) and <statement was true> or <statement was false>
```

It's the same as C#'s:

```
return statement
    ? trueValue
    : falseValue;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a matter of [operator precedence](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

In the case of your expressions, the implicit ordering is as follows

```
((len(str) < 2) and str) or ('doh ' + str + ' /doh')
```

In the case of `str = ""`, `len(str) < 2` evaluates `True`, but `str`, an empty string, evaluates to `False`, thus the `and` expression is `False`, so the right operand of the `or` binary op becomes the result of the expression.

For the case of `str = "abc"`, `len(str) < 2` is `False`, so the `and` expression short-circuits as `False`, and the expression to the right of the `or` is the result.

For the case of `str = "ab"`, `len(str) < 2` is True, so the `and` expression passes its right operand to the `or` binary operator, and since `bool("ab") == True`, the value of `str` becomes the result of the expression.

As you can see, using `and`/`or` will not work similarly to other language's ternary operators if your result in the case of a `True` condition is equivalent to `False`, e.g.
`True and 0 or 1` yields `1`, whereas using `0 if True else 1` yields `0`.

I'd recommend using python's ternary if/else expression, e.g.:

```
str if len(str) < 2 else 'doh ' + str + ' /doh'
```

Comment: Sorry, nope that's not it; this isn't a logical and/or; this is a ternary statement. I'll explain in my answer... Toclarify, I was omitting the return because I ran this statement directly into IDLE by typing "str = ''"<return>"len(str) < 2 and str or 'doh ' + str + ' /doh'"

Comment: Prior to python 2.6, python didn't support ternary operators, but because of the low binding + short-circuiting of logical and/or operators, you can use them to simulate a ternary operator as you describe, but `x and y or z` will not work if `bool(y) == False`.  In python 2.6+, use the `y if x else z` ternary expression instead.

Comment: I apologise, you're absolutely right; I was mistaking the form for a ternary operator to something else entirely; def f_b(str): str if len(str)<2 else str[-1]+str[1:-1]+str[0] works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
def front_times(str, n):
    return str[0:3] * n
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Could you explain how this solves the issue in the question? Thanks!